# How to update pivot table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

My header question looks so broad. Let me just describe it below.

I have 3 tables the `posts`, `tags`, and `post_tags`. I have use `syncWithoutDetaching` and so far its working fine. My only issue is when I do updating, it does not do the exact thing I expected.

Lets say I have already existing data(below picture).

[image]

And I want to send again another data

```
"tags":[1,3]
```

I expect using `syncWithoutDetaching` it would output these data below

[image]

But it returns it results into three like below

[image]

---

Someone knows how to achieve this expectation, I think `syncWithoutDetaching` is not the perfect fit for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the behavior that you are after is Sync **with** detaching. So use `sync()`

Basicly, when you use `sync`, giving it `"tag":[1,4]` will remove existing entries and add the new ones, so only tag id 1 and 4 will still be there

Using `syncWithoutDetaching`, giving it `"tag":[1,4]` will add the tag id 1 and 4 on top of what is already in there (without risk of duplication)

Comment: hi I have used `sync` but it has same result.

Comment: @JuanCervantes Maybe you have a problem with the relation declaration. can you add that to your question. Sync should remove the IDs that are not provided.

Comment: wait I'll retry :)

Comment: ahhh I'll mistakenly reversed the syncing instead of `$post->tags`, I used `$tags->posts` Your answer works